# Image in the header is not scaled correctly

Tags: html, css

The image in the header is not scaled, no matter what I set in the height property. You can see in the fiddle example, it's looks to me like it's less then 1px inaccurate.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4wwegnt/

NOTICE: If you look at the fiddle, you need to ZOOM OUT of the "result", in order to see the small height differences i'm talking about between the blue and the orange. Also, bottom of the cards suppose to be outside of the header.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img class="size" src="http://www.governorofpoker.com/new/img/logo-blue.jpg" />
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#FFF9E1;
}
header {
    height: 185px;
    background-color:#FA6F19;
    text-align:center;
}
img.size {    
        height:223px;
}
```

Comment: Why is the image larger than the header it's in?

Comment: Notwithstanding Pauld_D's comment, it's not clear what you're asking; you have an image, and it's sized according to the `.size` rule.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u4wwegnt/6/

Comment: Removing the space in the fiddle of @Paulie_D http://jsfiddle.net/u4wwegnt/5/

Comment: the bottom of the cards suppose to be outside of the header, exactly like in the fiddle, only there's a weird small difference between the height of the image and the height of the header. You need to get closer to see the difference between the blue of the image and the orange of the header.

Comment: I see what you are doing, and it looks fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE (latest versions).  You might be looking an optical illusion because of the high contrast between the blue and the orange.

Comment: You think? I changed the colors so you can see, but i see it also if the colors are the same (like they are, originally). The designer also said there are height differences... :\

Answer (score 0):

Width my friend:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4wwegnt/4/

```
body {
    background:#FFF9E1;
}
header {
    height: 185px;
    background-color:#FA6F19;
    text-align:center;
}
img.size {    
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It's not that... I colored to header in a different color so you can see my problem. there is a small difference between the height of the image and the height of the header.